# WSO2 api manager vs ESB analytics

Tags: wso2-appm, wso2-esb

Both the new version of api manager (2.0 and ESB (5.0) come with analytics component.

Does anyone know if a shared instance of analytics server can be used for both products (esb and api mgr)? or do you think analytics is a platform specific component and needs to be installed along with each platform?

Also, what is recommended practice for installing analytics server - on esb/api manager server or on a separate instance?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK its not possible. In the latest APIM and ESB it's recommended to use the analytics components packed with each product. The reason is latest versions of these two products has product specific analytic components.

However in the older versions of APIM(https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+WSO2+DAS) and ESB(https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Publish+Event+Mediator) had the ability to publish events to WSO2 DAS which can be used as a shared analytics server instance. But that is not encouraged in the latest versions.

So its better if you can use the integrated analytics servers for this purpose.

Comment: One more question, In the case of active/passive instance of esb ( eg. esb1, esb2), do you think both esb instances will point to a single instance of esb analytics component? If so, this esb analytics component should run on a separate analytics server, and not on esb server correct?

Comment: Yeah,IMO it is possible. both active and passive instances can point to same esb analytics component.

Answer (score 0):

you can use DAS 3.1.0 and configure APIM 2.0.0 and ESB 5.0.0. Each integrated analytics servers are DAS plus additional analytics features. So you can get DAS 3.1.0 and install both APIM and ESB analytics features on the DAS configure.

refer [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Installing+WSO2+APIM+Analytics+Features) for install feature on DAS.